# ContextBoundObject Throws a Remoting Error After Await

Tags: c#, async-await, custom-attributes

I have some logging code that was written to intercept method calls using ContextBoundObject s and a ContextAttribute.  The code is based on a Code Project [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8436/Intercepting-method-calls-in-C-an-approach-to-AOSD).

This all worked fine until we started using this library with code that leverages async and await.  Now we get remoting errors when running the code.  Here is a simple example that reproduces the issue:

```
public class OhMyAttribute : ContextAttribute
{
    public OhMyAttribute() : base("OhMy")
    {
    }
}

[OhMy]
public class Class1 : ContextBoundObject
{
    private string one = "1";
    public async Task Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(one);
        await Task.Delay(50);
        Console.WriteLine(one);
    }
}
```

When we invoke `Method1` we get the following `RemotingException` on the second `Console.WriteLine`:

```
Remoting cannot find field 'one' on type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Class1'.
```

Is there any way to get around this problem using built in C# methods or do we have to look at an alternative solution like PostSharp?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but that code is not even in the `Class1` class. Check the exception's stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more general workaround.

It has the following deficiencies:

- It does not support changing the `SynchronizationContext` within the `ContextBoundObject`. It will `throw` in that case.
- It does not support the case of using `await` when `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null **and** the `TaskScheduler.Current` is not the `TaskScheduler.Default`.  In this scenario, normally `await` would capture the `TaskScheduler` and use that to post the remainder of the work, but since this solution sets the `SynchronizationContext` the `TaskScheduler` would not be captured.  Thus, when this situation is detected, it will `throw`.
- It does not support using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` since that will cause the `SynchronizationContext` to not be captured.  Unfortunately, I could not detect this case.  However, if the user does want to get `.ConfigureAwait(false)` like behavior for the underlying pass-through `SynchronizationContext`, they can use a custom awaiter (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22417031/495262).

One interesting thing here is that I've attempted to create a "pass through" `SynchronizationContext`.  That is, I didn't want to overwrite any existing `SynchronizationContext`, but rather retain its behavior and layer on top of it the behavior of doing the work in the proper context.  Any comments on a better approach are welcome.

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation;
    using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
    using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var c1 = new Class1();
                var t = c1.Method1();
                Func<Task> f = c1.Method1;
                f.BeginInvoke(null, null);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        [MyContext]
        public class Class1 : ContextBoundObject
        {
            private string one = "1";
            public async Task Method1()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(one);
                await Task.Delay(50);
                Console.WriteLine(one);
            }
        }

        sealed class MyContextAttribute : ContextAttribute
        {
            public MyContextAttribute()
                : base("My")
            {
            }

            public override void GetPropertiesForNewContext(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
            {
                if (ctorMsg == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("ctorMsg");

                ctorMsg.ContextProperties.Add(new ContributeInstallContextSynchronizationContextMessageSink());
            }

            public override bool IsContextOK(Context ctx, IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        sealed class ContributeInstallContextSynchronizationContextMessageSink : IContextProperty, IContributeServerContextSink
        {
            public ContributeInstallContextSynchronizationContextMessageSink()
            {
            }

            public IMessageSink GetServerContextSink(IMessageSink nextSink)
            {
                return new InstallContextSynchronizationContextMessageSink(nextSink);
            }

            public string Name { get { return "ContributeInstallContextSynchronizationContextMessageSink"; } }

            public bool IsNewContextOK(Context ctx)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public void Freeze(Context ctx)
            {
            }
        }

        sealed class InstallContextSynchronizationContextMessageSink : IMessageSink
        {
            readonly IMessageSink m_NextSink;

            public InstallContextSynchronizationContextMessageSink(IMessageSink nextSink)
            {
                m_NextSink = nextSink;
            }

            public IMessageSink NextSink
            {
                get { return m_NextSink; }
            }

            public IMessageCtrl AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
            {
                var contextSyncContext = new ContextSynchronizationContext(SynchronizationContext.Current);
                var syncContextReplacer = new SynchronizationContextReplacer(contextSyncContext);

                DelegateMessageSink.SyncProcessMessageDelegate replySyncDelegate = (n, m) => SyncProcessMessageDelegateForAsyncReply(n, m, syncContextReplacer);
                var newReplySink = new DelegateMessageSink(replySink, replySyncDelegate, null);
                return m_NextSink.AsyncProcessMessage(msg, newReplySink);
            }

            public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
            {
                var contextSyncContext = new ContextSynchronizationContext(SynchronizationContext.Current);
                using (new SynchronizationContextReplacer(contextSyncContext))
                {
                    var ret = m_NextSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg);
                    return ret;
                }
            }

            private IMessage SyncProcessMessageDelegateForAsyncReply(IMessageSink nextSink, IMessage msg, SynchronizationContextReplacer syncContextReplacer)
            {
                syncContextReplacer.Dispose();
                return nextSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg);
            }

            private void PreChecks()
            {
                if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
                    return;

                if (TaskScheduler.Current != TaskScheduler.Default)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("InstallContextSynchronizationContextMessageSink does not support calling methods with SynchronizationContext.Current as null while Taskscheduler.Current is not TaskScheduler.Default");
            }
        }

        sealed class SynchronizationContextReplacer : IDisposable
        {
            SynchronizationContext m_original;
            SynchronizationContext m_new;

            public SynchronizationContextReplacer(SynchronizationContext syncContext)
            {
                m_original = SynchronizationContext.Current;
                m_new = syncContext;
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(m_new);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                // We don't expect the SynchronizationContext to be changed during the lifetime of the SynchronizationContextReplacer
                if (SynchronizationContext.Current != m_new)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("SynchronizationContext was changed unexpectedly.");

                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(m_original);
            }
        }

        sealed class ContextSynchronizationContext : PassThroughSynchronizationConext
        {
            readonly Context m_context;

            private ContextSynchronizationContext(SynchronizationContext passThroughSyncContext, Context ctx)
                : base(passThroughSyncContext)
            {
                if (ctx == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("ctx");

                m_context = ctx;
            }

            public ContextSynchronizationContext(SynchronizationContext passThroughSyncContext)
                : this(passThroughSyncContext, Thread.CurrentContext)
            {
            }

            protected override SynchronizationContext CreateCopy(SynchronizationContext copiedPassThroughSyncContext)
            {
                return new ContextSynchronizationContext(copiedPassThroughSyncContext, m_context);
            }

            protected override void CreateSendOrPostCallback(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
            {
                CrossContextDelegate ccd = () => d(state);
                m_context.DoCallBack(ccd);
            }
        }

        abstract class PassThroughSynchronizationConext : SynchronizationContext
        {
            readonly SynchronizationContext m_passThroughSyncContext;

            protected PassThroughSynchronizationConext(SynchronizationContext passThroughSyncContext)
                : base()
            {
                m_passThroughSyncContext = passThroughSyncContext;
            }

            protected abstract void CreateSendOrPostCallback(SendOrPostCallback d, object state);
            protected abstract SynchronizationContext CreateCopy(SynchronizationContext copiedPassThroughSyncContext);

            public sealed override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
            {
                var d2 = CreateSendOrPostCallback(d);
                if (m_passThroughSyncContext != null)
                    m_passThroughSyncContext.Post(d2, state);
                else
                    base.Post(d2, state);
            }

            public sealed override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
            {
                var d2 = CreateSendOrPostCallback(d);
                if (m_passThroughSyncContext != null)
                    m_passThroughSyncContext.Send(d2, state);
                else
                    base.Send(d2, state);
            }

            public sealed override SynchronizationContext CreateCopy()
            {
                var copiedSyncCtx = m_passThroughSyncContext != null ? m_passThroughSyncContext.CreateCopy() : null;
                return CreateCopy(copiedSyncCtx);
            }

            public sealed override void OperationCompleted()
            {
                if (m_passThroughSyncContext != null)
                    m_passThroughSyncContext.OperationCompleted();
                else
                    base.OperationCompleted();
            }

            public sealed override void OperationStarted()
            {
                if (m_passThroughSyncContext != null)
                    m_passThroughSyncContext.OperationStarted();
                else
                    base.OperationStarted();
            }

            public sealed override int Wait(IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout)
            {
                return m_passThroughSyncContext != null ?
                    m_passThroughSyncContext.Wait(waitHandles, waitAll, millisecondsTimeout) :
                    base.Wait(waitHandles, waitAll, millisecondsTimeout);
            }

            private SendOrPostCallback CreateSendOrPostCallback(SendOrPostCallback d)
            {
                SendOrPostCallback sopc = s => CreateSendOrPostCallback(d, s);
                return sopc;
            }
        }

        sealed class DelegateMessageSink : IMessageSink
        {
            public delegate IMessage SyncProcessMessageDelegate(IMessageSink nextSink, IMessage msg);
            public delegate IMessageCtrl AsyncProcessMessageDelegate(IMessageSink nextSink, IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink);

            readonly IMessageSink m_NextSink;
            readonly SyncProcessMessageDelegate m_syncProcessMessageDelegate;
            readonly AsyncProcessMessageDelegate m_asyncProcessMessageDelegate;

            public DelegateMessageSink(IMessageSink nextSink, SyncProcessMessageDelegate syncProcessMessageDelegate, AsyncProcessMessageDelegate asyncProcessMessageDelegate)
            {
                m_NextSink = nextSink;
                m_syncProcessMessageDelegate = syncProcessMessageDelegate;
                m_asyncProcessMessageDelegate = asyncProcessMessageDelegate;
            }

            public IMessageCtrl AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
            {
                return (m_asyncProcessMessageDelegate != null) ?
                    m_asyncProcessMessageDelegate(m_NextSink, msg, replySink) :
                    m_NextSink.AsyncProcessMessage(msg, replySink);
            }

            public IMessageSink NextSink
            {
                get { return m_NextSink; }
            }

            public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
            {
                return (m_syncProcessMessageDelegate != null) ?
                    m_syncProcessMessageDelegate(m_NextSink, msg) :
                    m_NextSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:** Remoting calls do not work on private fields.  The `async`/`await` rewriting causes an attempt to make a remoting call on a private field.

The issue can be reproduced without `async`/`await`.  And demonstrating it this way is helpful in understanding what is going on in the `async`/`await` case:

```
[OhMy]
public class Class2 : ContextBoundObject
{
    private string one = "1";

    public void Method1()
    {
        var nc = new NestedClass(this);
    }

    public class NestedClass
    {
        public NestedClass(Class2 c2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c2.one);  // Note: nested classes are allowed access to outer classes privates
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var c2 = new Class2();

    // This call causes no problems:
    c2.Method1();

    // This, however, causes the issue.
    var nc = new Class2.NestedClass(c2);
}
```

Let's walk through what happens line by line:

1. In Main, we start out in **Context0**
2. Since `Class2` is a `ContextBoundObject` and since the `OhMyAttribute` considers the current context unacceptable, an instance of `Class2` is created in **Context1** (I'll call this `c2_real`, and what is returned and stored in `c2` is a remoting proxy to `c2_real`.
3. When `c2.Method1()` is called, it is called on the remote proxy.  Since we are in Context0, the remote proxy realizes it is not in the correct context so it switches to Context1, and the code within `Method1` is executed.
   3.a Within `Method1` we call the `NestedClass` constructor which uses `c2.one`.  In this case, we are already in Context1, so the `c2.one` requires no context switches and so we are using the `c2_real` object directly.

Now, the problematic case:

1. We create a new `NestedClass` passing in the remote proxy `c2`.  No context switches occur here because `NestedClass` is not a `ContextBoundObject`.
2. Within the `NestedClass` ctor, it access c2.one.  The remote proxy notices that we are still in Context0, and so it attempts to remote this call to Context1.  This fails because `c2.one` is a private field. You'll see in `Object.GetFieldInfo` it is only looking for Public fields:

   ```
   private FieldInfo GetFieldInfo(String typeName, String fieldName)
   {
       // ...

       FieldInfo fldInfo = t.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Public | 
                                                   BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                   BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
       if(null == fldInfo)
       {
   #if FEATURE_REMOTING 
           throw new RemotingException(String.Format(
               CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Environment.GetResourceString("Remoting_BadField"),
                                               fieldName, typeName));            
       // ...

       }

       return fldInfo;
   }
   ```

So, **How does `async`/`await` end up causing this same issue?**

The `async`/`await` causes your `Class1` to get rewritten such that it uses a nested class with a state machine (used ILSpy to generate):

```
public class Class1 : ContextBoundObject
{
    // ...
    private struct <Method1>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
    {
        public int <>1__state;
        public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder;
        public Class1 <>4__this;
        private TaskAwaiter <>u__$awaiter1;
        private object <>t__stack;

        void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
        {
            try
            {
                int num = this.<>1__state;
                if (num != -3)
                {
                    TaskAwaiter taskAwaiter;
                    if (num != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(this.<>4__this.one);
                        taskAwaiter = Task.Delay(50).GetAwaiter();
                        if (!taskAwaiter.IsCompleted)
                        {
                            this.<>1__state = 0;
                            this.<>u__$awaiter1 = taskAwaiter;
                            this.<>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TaskAwaiter, Class1.<Method1>d__0>(ref taskAwaiter, ref this);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        taskAwaiter = this.<>u__$awaiter1;
                        this.<>u__$awaiter1 = default(TaskAwaiter);
                        this.<>1__state = -1;
                    }
                    taskAwaiter.GetResult();
                    taskAwaiter = default(TaskAwaiter);
                    Console.WriteLine(this.<>4__this.one);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.<>1__state = -2;
                this.<>t__builder.SetException(exception);
                return;
            }
            this.<>1__state = -2;
            this.<>t__builder.SetResult();
        }

        // ... 
    }

    private string one = "1";

    public Task Method1()
    {
        Class1.<Method1>d__0 <Method1>d__;
        <Method1>d__.<>4__this = this;
        <Method1>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
        <Method1>d__.<>1__state = -1;
        AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder = <Method1>d__.<>t__builder;
        <>t__builder.Start<Class1.<Method1>d__0>(ref <Method1>d__);
        return <Method1>d__.<>t__builder.Task;
    }
}
```

The important thing to notice is that

- It's created a nested structure which has access to the privates of `Class1`
- The `this` variable is lifted and stored in the nested class.

So, what happens here is that

1. On the initial call to `c1.Method1()` the remoting proxy notices we are in Context0, and that it needs to switch to Context1.
2. Eventually, `MoveNext` is called, and `c1.one` is called.  Since we are already in Context1, no context switch is necessary (so the issue doesn't occur).
3. Later, since a continuation was registered, a call to `MoveNext` will occur again to execute the rest of the code after the `await`.  However, this call to `MoveNext` will not occur inside a call to one of `Class1`'s methods.  Thus, when the code `c1.one` is executed this time, we will be in Context0.  The remoting proxy notices we are in Context0, and attempts a context switch.  This causes the same failure as above since `c1.one` is a private field.

**Workaround:**
I'm not sure of a general workaround, but for this specific case you can work around the issue by not using the `this` reference in the method. I.e.:

```
public async Task Method1()
{
    var temp = one;
    Console.WriteLine(temp);
    await Task.Delay(50);
    Console.WriteLine(temp);
}
```

Or switch to using a private property instead of a field.