# Is it safe to use ThreadStatic data and set Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity on an ASP.NET background thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As discussed nicely [here](http://piers7.blogspot.co.uk/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273318/8479), you should use `HttpContext.Current.Items` rather than a `ThreadStatic` variable to store data for an ASP.NET request, since your request might be processed by more than one thread.

How about if you want to do something on a background thread? Is it safe to use `ThreadStatic` data and to set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` to avoid having to push 'global' data through all your methods? I'm assuming that it's fine, but would like to be sure. For instance, I'm not explicitly using any `await` in the code executed on a background thread but libraries I'm calling probably are; might ASP.NET use my thread to do other things while such async code is not active? If that's the case, what's a safe way to set some 'thread-static' data and user information on a thread before running it?

I'm well aware of [the pitfalls](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) of running code on background threads in ASP.NET. But sometimes you've gotta do what you've gotta do. In my case we're not yet on .NET 4.5.2 so can't use [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx#v452), so we're using [Nito.AspNetBackgroundTasks](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) to run the background tasks. This internally uses `Task.Run()`.

For example, I'd do something like this:

```
public class SomeController
{    
    public void AControllerMethod()
    {
        // Get the data set earlier on the HttpContext
        var theData = HttpContext.Current.Items["importantKey"];
        var thePrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
        // Pass it to the background thread method
        BackgroundTaskManager.Run(() => DoStuffInBackground(theData, thePrincipal));        
    }

    private void DoStuffInBackground(string someData, IPrincipal user)
    {
        // Store the data & principal for use by logic classes later
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = user;
        MyContextService.BackgroundData["importantKey"] = someData;

        // do some things, some of which would call:
        aLogicClass.DoSomethingDeepInLogicCode();
    }    
}

public class ExampleLogicClass
{    
    private void DoSomethingDeepInLogicCode()
    {
        // get the context info
        var user = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        var theData = MyContextService.GetContextData("importantKey");

        // .. do stuff with user & data....        
    }    
}

public static class MyContextService
{     
    [ThreadStatic]
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string,object> BackgroundData = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,object>();

    // Gets data from HttpContext or from BackgroundData 
    public object GetContextData(string key)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        { 
            var data = HttpContext.Current.Items[key]; 
            if (data != null) return data;
        } 
        if (BackgroundData.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return BackgroundData[key];
        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

**UPDATE:**

From a [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516730/is-the-use-of-threadstatic-at-odds-with-asynchronous-code) [more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx) [reading](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) I guess I should use [CallContext.LogicalSetData()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.logicalsetdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and LogicalGetData() to set/get the equivalent of ThreadLocal/ThreadStatic data. (Or [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx) in .net 4.6).

More clarification from someone who knows this stuff properly would be great.