# DebuggerStepThrough, DebuggerHidden don't work in an async-await method

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, exception, async-await

When you turn on the ["Break when an exception is thrown"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) feature in the Visual Studio debugger it breaks everywhere for selected exception types. The way to tell it not to break in a specific method is to [decorate these methods with `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute (or `DebuggerHidden`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424436/885318).

This, *evidently*, doesn't work for an `async` method for some reason.
Here's a snippet that reproduces the issue. The debugger *will* break inside the `TestAsync` even though it's marked with the attributes and it will *not* break inside `Test` as excepted ( the only difference between them is the first is marked with the `async` keyword):

```
public class Attributes
{
    public async Task Run()
    {
        await TestAsync();
        await Test();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public async Task TestAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Async");
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public Task Test()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("sync");
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

So, is this behavior intended? Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: It is a fairly inevitable flaw in the way the C# compiler implements asynch, your method is *rewritten* into a hidden class.  Which does not get those same attributes.  Use ildasm.exe to look under the hood.

Comment: @HansPassant I originally thought it doesn't work only after an await is used (ie the continuation), but apparently it always fails.

Comment: It works to me in the .NET 6 with Jetbrains Rider even in async code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attributes don't play well with async/await since async methods get re-written under the covers--and the attributes do not follow.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22412597/495262 for a similar situation.

Comment: Note that `DebuggerStepThrough` and `DebuggerHidden` are subject to interpretation by a particular debugger.  They have no particular meaning to the CLR.  They may well work as documented in future updates of VS.

Comment: @EricJ. It may, but as of 2024 (VS 17.8) it still doesn't.